# Why aren't nested raids more common in home systems?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I never even knew this existed until now. 
But I know a lot of people have raid configurations at home, usually raid 0 for performance. 
Well my question is why aren't nested raids the suggested solution? Wouldn't raid 0+5 be better than just having a raid 0 for performance because it would also offer the redundancy as well? That seems more efficient to me.

Comment: It is more efficient most people just don't have the required storage devices required to implement it.

Comment: Raid has traditionally be cheap for businesses, but expensive for individuals. Most soft/fake raid solutions are at the best underperforming, and at worst unreliable, and a reliably raid card is not exactly cheap. And then theres all the disks....

Comment: What they said, plus there's a certain amount of tech savvy needed to even know what RAID is and why it's useful, let alone be able to choose between all the various RAID types. My mom does quite well with her iMac but I'm sure hasn't a clue what RAID is and if I tried to explain it would probably be surprised to learn disks can crash. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is RAID 0 and there is RAID 5, but there is no such thing as RAID 0+5.  The only "nested" RAID levels are RAID 10 or RAID 0+1.  Any other combination wouldn't make sense.

Secondly, a RAID 5 is actually slower than a RAID 0 would be and you lose the capacity of one of the disks in the array.  Every write requires a parity recalculation.  That's how the redundancy works.  The parity information takes both extra time and extra storage space to maintain.

Lastly, it's important to note that redundancy is not a backup solution.  The **only** purpose of redundancy is to reduce or eliminate downtime should one of the drives fail.  This is important for companies because downtime disrupts business operations, but it's not that big a deal for consumers.  The worst thing that will happen for a home user is spending a weekend setting their computer back up after a crash.

Bottom line is this:
If you have three hard drives (the minimum required for a RAID 5), you're better off doing a RAID 0 with two of them and using the third as a backup drive.  It'd be faster and cheaper for you as a consumer.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for not using a RAID 50 or 5+0 at home is the large number of drives required and the ability to set it up.  RAID 50 requires a minimum of 6 drives to work and most home users don't want to make that level of commitment. It isn't just the drives however, it's the larger case to hold the drives, the RAID card that supports RAID 50, fans to keep the drives cool, a larger power supply, and so on.